# iOS GMaps delegate mapView: markerInfoWindow: not implemented

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am trying to create custom Info Window for marker. I am using Google Maps SDK for iOS.

I have created custom XIB file with all objects. Created class for it.

Called `GMSMapViewDelegate` in Header file

in implementation file I implemented following method:

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker {

    NSLog(@"Implementing delegate Method");

    CustomInfoWindow *infoWindow =  [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                 loadNibNamed:@"InfoWindow"
                                        owner:self
                                      options:nil]
                                objectAtIndex:0];

    infoWindow.title.text = @"This is title";
    infoWindow.address.text = @"This is address";
    infoWindow.status.text = @"Here will be status";

    return infoWindow;
}
```

But there is still default marker. What could be the issue?

Thanks for help.

Comment: call markerInfoWindow: method or not ?

Comment: What did you mean by call method? I don't have to call delegate methods

Comment: i means, it automatic call when you add marker ?

Comment: delegate method not called at all. I also put nslog to monitor it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try if not add GMSMapView Delegate

You add GMSMapView Delegate in in implementation file

> ```
> GMSMapView * mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:viewmapbaseView.bounds camera:camera];
> mapView_.delegate=self;
> ```